How many doubly stochastic matrices with $Dp=q$ are there?
Let $p,q$ be $n$-dimensional probability vectors such that $p$ majorizes $q$ (i.e. $p$ is less mixed than $q$). It is a classic result that this is the case if and only if there exists a doubly stochastic $n\times n$ matrix such that $Dp=q$. I'm interested in the set $D(p,q)$ of doubly stochastic matrices that map $p$ to $q$.
What is known about this set? Clearly, $D(p,q)$ is a convex set. What are the extreme points? Are there doubly stochastic matrices $D\in D(p,q)$ that are optimal in some sense?
It is also clear that any degeneracy in $p$ and $q$ makes for a symmetry of $D(p,q)$, e.g., if $p=(\frac12, \frac14,\frac14)$ then $D\in D(p,q) \iff D P_{(12)} \in D(p,q)$ where $P_{(12)}$ is the permutation matrix that swaps the first and second entry. Are there other symmetries?
If we assume that both $p$ and $q$ are non-degenerate (i.e., all entries are distinct), this symmetry disappears. How large is $D(p,q)$ now? Is there a unique d.s. matrix in this case?

This question is discussed in the book A. Marshall, I. Olkin, and B. Arnold. Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications. 2nd ed. New York: Springer, 2011., more precisely on page 54 ff. in the section "The Doubly Stochastic Matrices of a Given Majorization". After presenting some example and related results, on page 59 they give the following result (Ch. 2, Lemma G.6); I'll substitute some of their notation to make things more accessible:

Let $ p,q \in \mathbb R^n$ with $p_1\geq\ldots\geq p_n$, $q_1\geq\ldots\geq q_n$ be given such that $q \prec p$.
There exists a unique doubly stochastic matrix $D$ with $Dp=q$ if and
only if the following two conditions hold:

$p$ has distinct components
For some integer $m \leq n$, $p$ and $q$ have coincidences at positions
$1 \leq k_1 < k_2 < \ldots < k_{m−1} \leq n − 1$, where $k_j − k_{j−1}\leq 2$ for each $j = 1, 2, \ldots , m-2$.


So the condition you identified already that the entries of $p$ have to be distinct is not enough to guarantee uniqueness of $D$. Marshall et al. also give an example to illustrate this (Ch. 2, Example G.2): For $p=(5,3,1)$ (distinct entries!) and $q=(4,3,2)$ they show that the set $D(p,q)$ has four extreme points.
